# use "Like" Expression, LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, sql-like

I spent long time trying to fix this but I'm not getting anywhere, so i help someone helps me.
I have a search form where I wish to use the Like % operator in the textbox.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var data = mg.DatabaseTable.Where(m => m.UserName.StartsWith(TextBoxUserID.Text) &&
                                       m.Content.Like(%TextBoxBarcode.Text&) &&
                                       m.Action.StartsWith(DropDownListStatus.Text) &&
                                       m.Site.Contains(TextBoxSite.Text));
```

I would like it to be possible to use `"%%"` in the `m.Content(textbox)` or however it's made.

I am aware the use of `StartsWith`, `EndWith` and `Contains`. I would like to make it possible to choose how to query the search by using `"like %"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
m.Content.StartsWith(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
```

for

```
like 'search%'
```

or:

```
m.Content.EndsWith(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
```

for

```
like '%search'
```

or:

```
m.Content.Contains(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
```

for

```
like '%search%'
```

If you want the user to be able to choose the type of search then you'll need to have a switch and then three different queries. Either replicate the query or perform the basic query once and then filter the results of that depending on the switch:

```
var data = mg.DatabaseTable.Where(m => m.UserName.StartsWith(TextBoxUserID.Text) &&
                                       m.Action.StartsWith(DropDownListStatus.Text) &&
                                       m.Site.Contains(TextBoxSite.Text));

if (searchMode == StartsWith)
{
    return data.Where(m => m.Content.StartsWith(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
}
else if (searchMode == EndsWith)
{
    return data.Where(m => m.Content.EndsWith(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
}
else
{
    return data.Where(m => m.Content.Contains(TextBoxBarcode.Text);
}
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - why? These are examples, you wouldn't necessarily be using all three in the same code.

Comment: I just edited my answer, because  i would like to avoid the "Contains". since i want it to be possible to use search something like this: "%Myname%something%"

Comment: @MishMish - I'd build up the string separately. Though your question is unclear.

Comment: @ChrisF Pranay Ranga used sample data for his answer, you used OP data thus it looked like complete solution, not like an example. Ans remark was not about using all three - it was about evaluating property value.

Comment: Pranay answer is nice, but yeah it does not fell my needs since i need to use the "%" in search query